# Regenerating the output after deleting it in periodic way in tcpdump

Tags: bash, file, awk, tcpdump

I need to monitoring the network using a tcpdump. However I need to delete its output(train.txt) every 5 seconds from its folder manually. I am looking for a approach to regenerate the output in a bash file. In other words, as I delete the output of tcpdump, it generates a new output with new contents. Here is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE="/media/sf_sharedsaeed/train.txt"
#Change the eth for each host first
tcpdump -i h1-eth0 -l -e -n 'port 80' & > /media/sf_sharedsaeed/train.txt
while true
do
if [ -f $FILE ]; then
   echo "******************* tcpdump do its job well******************* "
else
    #now interrupt the process. get its PID:
    pid=$(ps -e | pgrep tcpdump)
    echo $pid

    kill -2 $pid
    echo "File $FILE does not exist. tcpdump make it again."
    tcpdump -i h1-eth0 -l -e -n  > /media/sf_sharedsaeed/train.txt

fi

done
```

The problem is that, as the output deleted, no new output file generated anymore. Please help me.

Update:
I used this code to delete the file content instead of deleting the file: (using cat /dev/null > $FILE)

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE="train.txt"
second=5

while true
do
awk '{print $10" "$12}' $FILE | sort | uniq -c > output.txt
echo "New output.txt generated."
#truncate -s 0 $FILE
cat /dev/null > $FILE
echo "wait for 5 seconds ..."
sleep $second
done
```

As I used it, the output(train.txt) is not fill completely. Some data will missed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about the redirection operator `>`?

```
cat /dev/null > train.txt
```

This way you are just truncating the file `train.txt`, i.e.: setting its size to zero.

Ideally, the process writing to `train.txt` should have opened this file in *append* mode (i.e.: by means of the redirection operator `>>` in `bash`). 
If so, this process will always set the its *file offset* to the size of the file before writing it.
Otherwise a so called *file hole* would be created the next time it writes to `train.txt`.

---

### Basically:

```
tcpdump -i h1-eth0 -l -e -n 'port 80' & >> /media/sf_sharedsaeed/train.txt
```

and, do **not** delete `train.txt`, do this instead (i.e.: truncate the file):

```
cat /dev/null > /media/sf_sharedsaeed/train.txt
```

---

### Note:

Instead of truncating `tain.txt` manually you could periodically check its size and then truncate it on demand when the file it's too big.

Comment: Thanks for your replying. I have tested it, but it does't work! :(

Comment: @saeedtalaee which process is writing to `trains.txt` ?

Comment: @saeedtalaee use `cat /dev/null/ > trains.txt` instead of deleting `trains.txt`.

Comment: the process that belongs to tcpdump.

Comment: I deleted the kill part even, but it shows me this:
File /media/sf_sharedsaeed/train.txt does not exist. tcpdump make it again.
tcpdump: h1-eth0: No such device exists
(SIOCGIFHWADDR: No such device)

Comment: @saeedtalaee did you already try change the redirection of `tcpdump` from `>` to `>>` ?

Comment: It works man! I forget that in my second test! Thanks a lot! :))